# Changing string value on google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have form with some description of it. And i need to change some words inside of it. Everywhere it is written that this is a specialized language, but I just need to rewrite string value. how I can do it?
I need to change something like this -> "test 2017 test" to "test 2018 test"
I think i need to use some javascript function but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I suggest you have a look on some beginner tutorials for Javascript.

Comment: Already dealt with this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
var str = "Some string containing test 2017 test and other stuff"
Logger.log(str.replace("test 2017 test","test 2018 test"));
```